# Why can't toPx() work outside of Canvas in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the below code, `toPx()` works in `Canvas` but not in `Surface`.
Why?

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp)) {
    val textPaint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
        textSize = 32.dp.toPx()
    }
}

Surface(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp)) {
    val textPaint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
        textSize = 32.dp.toPx() // Error `toPx()`
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the error you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `toPx()` function is defined inside  a [`Density`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density) interface and you cannot use it unless you provide it.  The `Canvas` works with a [`DrawScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope) which provides it.

To use it you can provide the `Density` using the[**`LocalDensity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#localdensity) provider.
Something like:

```
val dpToPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { 32.dp.toPx() }
```